# jQuery datepicker shows up behind popup

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, fancybox

I am using two different jQuery plugins that I'm trying to combine. First I'm using a popup plugin from http://fancybox.net/home. When the popup shows I need to have a textfield with a datepicker inside the popup. The datepicker is from jQuery UI. The problem is that the datepicker always shows up behind the popup so it is impossible to select a date. Is this something I can change in some way?

My code:

```
<html>
    <a id="inline" href="#data">Open popup</a>

    <div style="display:none"><div id="data">
        <input id="datepicker" type="text">
    </div></div>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a#inline").fancybox();
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the z-index of the fancybox version you're using, can you check the CSS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set the z-index of the datepicker higher than that of the fancybox. The fancybox z-index is 1101, just set the datepicker to 1102 or anything higher and it should bring the datepicker to the front.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning the z-index used by fancybox.  That's a key detail that was lacking in other explanations,  which had left me thinking "meh - one thousand should be enough".

Answer (score 2):

use CSS -
`.datepicker{ z-index: 999999; }`

Answer (score 1):

.fancybox-inner{overflow:visible !important;}

this works for me